# script to remove middle character from multiple directories then rename files in subdirectories to include directory + file name

Tags: bash, shell, rename, removeall

I have two objectives I am trying to accomplish and need some help.

Here is the overview:

[image]

There are hundreds of folders/directories with random numbers ( 5555#5555 ) containing the same 001.pdf file. I would like to:

**1:** Remove the "#" symbol from every folder/directory

**2:** Rename the 001.pdf file to include the new folder numbers and the 001.pdf

**Desired result:** The folder `5555#5555` become `55555555` containing the `001.pdf` file that becomes `55555555.001.pdf`

[image]

Hope that makes sense and thanks.

Comment: Try `for dir in "*#*"; do mv "$dir" ${dir//#}; mv ${dir//#}/001.pdf ${dir//#}/${dir//#}.001.pdf; done`.

Comment: Or you can try `rename '#' '' *; for f in */001.pdf; do rename '/' '/'${f%%/*}. $f; done`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so update: Thanks for the suggestions. Here is what I got to work for me. Might not be the best way but hey.

```
  curdir=`pwd`
  for f in `find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name "*#*" -print`;
  do
   echo "folder is $f"
    newFolder=`echo $f | sed 's/#//g'`
    echo mv $f $newFolder
    mv $f $newFolder
    echo newfolder is $newFolder
    cd $newFolder
    for file  in `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%f\n'`; do
      echo "mv $file to ${newFolder}_$file"
      mv $file ${newFolder}_$file
    done
    cd $curdir
  done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for f in *#*;
do
  newFolder=$(echo ${f//%})
  mv $f $newFolder
  newFile=$(printf $newFolder".001.pdf")
  mv $newFolder/001.pdf $newFolder/$newFile
done
```

This should do it, although there may be more elegant solutions.  Change the regular expressions for the loop if you want to catch other files without `#`.